# PyDev not capturing unittest.TextTestRunner output?

Tags: python, pydev

The PyDev PyUnit perspective correctly displays the output of my unit tests when I run them as "Python unit-test" from the module they live in with this basic usage pattern:

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

However, when I import tests from another module like so...

```
import unittest
import mypackage.mytests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(module=mypackage.mytests)
```

...no tests are run.  When I run the same module as "Python Run" or from a terminal, it behaves correctly, so for some reason the PyUnit perspective is not loading the tests correctly.  I get the same results with this alternative method:

```
import unittest
import mypackage.mytests

tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(mypackage.mytests)
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(tests)
```

Is there another way to import a module containing TestCase derived classes and get PyDev to capture the output of the test runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev will not run your `__main__`, it'll collect the classes itself, so, you need to have your classes loaded in the module for it to find them (and do a run as > Python Unittest, or even use the Ctrl+F9 shortcut directly -- it won't show classes in that case, but pressing Enter directly after the Ctrl+F9 should work to run all the tests in the module in the latest PyDev).

e.g.:

```
import unittest 
from mypackage.mytests import *
```

If you had multiple and the TestCase classes had the same name, you'd need to do something as:

```
import unittest
from mypackage.mytests import Test as Test1
from mypackage.mytests2 import Test as Test2
...
```

In which case you'd probably be better by creating a simple helper to load all the classes from a module and put subclasses of TestCase in the current module with different names (should be straightforward doing this through a dir/getattr in the module).

Still, note that in PyDev you may select multiple files/folder and do a run as > Python unittest and it'll run all the tests it finds in the module (or recursively in a directory), so, that may already be enough for you depending on your use case.